# Getting better results from DHT22

Tags: arduino-uno, sensors

I am working on a dew point sensor, and I am using the Arduino Uno board with the DHT22 sensor. I have it taking a reading once ever 2 seconds and I am using the DHT.h library. 
The problem I am having is when I compare the values to our standard here the Humidity reads high and the Temp reads low. Is there anyway to get the values to read closer to what the standard is?

Comment: personal opinion - use a better sensor ... my DHT reads humidity low (very low in fact) and temperature high ... so opposite to your problem. I've had better success with the BME280, or a *DS18B20* for temperature plus a *HopeRF HH10D* for Humidity

Comment: calibrate the sensors

Comment: See this article which includes a section about calibration. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-check-and-calibrate-a-humidity-sensor/

Comment: Thanks for the answers, there were kind of what I was expecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a RH and Temp Calibrator I had access to I was able to get better results by all lines to adjust the RH and Temp to a better value. Basically a correction equation.